# Angular's ngRoute doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

Well, this is a topic I saw a lot around here, yet hadn't found anyone with the specific problem I got (or I didn't understand it as such ..)

So - I would start by saying that I try to run my SPA localy (not on a server of some sort..)
This, as I understood, denied me of using chrome/explorer, and moved to firefox :(

YET - the weirdest thing keeps happening - when I click on the links that suppose to change the adress properly, only adds a writing at the end of it.

What do I mean? when I click a link it should go from:

file:///C:/Users/saartk/Desktop/Python/New/conFusion/app/index.html#!/**contactus**

to:
 file:///C:/Users/saartk/Desktop/Python/New/conFusion/app/index.html#!/**menu**

Instead it becomes:
file:///C:/Users/saartk/Desktop/Python/New/conFusion/app/index.html#!/**contactus#%2Fmenu** 
The menu part is added to the default, unyeilding, contactus...

my code is as the following:

this is my html file (index.html): (relevent part is the navbar)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>    

    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="confusionApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><img src="images/logo.png" height="30" width="41"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/aboutus">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/menu">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                         Menu</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/contactus">
                     <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>         

    <header class="jumbotron">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create
                     a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will 
                     tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <footer class="row-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>: 
                         <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">
                         confusion@food.net</a>
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align="center">© Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

this is the ngRoute js file:

```
var app=angular.module('confusionApp',['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the contactus page
        .when('/contactus', {
            templateUrl : 'contactus.html',
            controller  : 'ContactController'
        })
        // route for the menu page
        .when('/menu', {
            templateUrl : 'menu.html',
            controller  : 'ctrlr'
        })
        // route for the dish details page
        .when('/menu/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'dishdetail.html',
            controller  : 'dishControl'
        })
        .otherwise('/contactus');
});
```

the controllers:

```
    'use strict'
var app=angular.module('confusionApp');

  app.controller('ctrlr',['$scope','pizzaService',function($scope,pizzaService){
   $scope.hide=true;
   $scope.toggle=function(){
       $scope.hide=!$scope.hide;
   }
   $scope.tab="";
   $scope.yosi=pizzaService.getDishes();
        $scope.select=function(setTab){
         $scope.tab=setTab;

        };
        $scope.isSelected=function(checkTab){
         return ($scope.tab==checkTab);
        };    
  }]);
   app.controller('ContactController',['$scope',function($scope){
       $scope.feedback= {myChannel:"",firstName:"",lastName:"",agree:false,email:""};
       $scope.channels=[{value:"Tel.",label:"Tele"},{value:"Email",label:"Mail"}];
       $scope.notChosen=false;

   }]);
   app.controller('FeedbackController',['$scope',function($scope){
       $scope.validate=function(){
           console.log($scope.feedback);
           if($scope.feedback.agree&&($scope.feedback.myChannel=="")){
               $scope.notChosen=true;
               console.log('incorrect');
           }
           else{
               $scope.feedback= {myChannel:"",firstName:"",lastName:"",agree:false,email:""};
               $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
               $scope.notChosen=false;
               console.log($scope.feedback);
           }
       }
   }]);




        app.controller('dishControl',['$scope','$routeParams','pizzaService',function($scope,pizzaService,$routeParams) {

            $scope.dish=pizzaService.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));
            $scope.commentNew={
                rating:4,
                comment:"",
                author:"",
                date:""
                };        
            $scope.isThis=function(num){
                if(num==$scope.commentNew.rating){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            };
            $scope.isCommentEmpty=function(){
                if($scope.commentNew.comment==""){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            };
            $scope.commentNow=function(){
                $scope.commentNew.date=Date();
                $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.commentNew);
                $scope.commentNew={rating:4,comment:'',author:'',date:''};
                $scope.dishForm.$setPristine();
            };
        }]);
```

and the services (data):

```
'use strict'
angular.module('confusionApp')
 .factory('pizzaService',function(){
     var object={};
     var dishes=[
                         {
                           _id:0,
                           sort:'',  
                           name:'Uthapizza',
                           image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                           category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot',
                           price:'4.99',
                           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2017-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           _id:1,
                           sort:'', 
                           name:'Zucchipakoda',
                           image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                           category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'',
                           price:'1.99',
                           description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2017-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           _id:2,
                           sort:'',
                           name:'Vadonut',
                           image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                           category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'New',
                           price:'1.99',
                           description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2017-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           _id:3,
                           sort:'', 
                           name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                           image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                           category: 'dessert',
                           label:'',
                           price:'2.99',
                           description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2017-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                        }
                        ];
     object.getDishes=function(){
         return dishes;
     };                
     object.getDish=function(num){
         return dishes[num];
     };   
     return object;
 });
```

so... what do you guys and gals think is the problem?

Lots of thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a similar problem back when I was working with the old angular but I can't seem to remember how I fixed it. In your hrefs, instead of using "#/route", how does it behave if you use "/route"?

Comment: sorry I am not getting it as your example seems to be working at my end ..let me know what your re looking for - http://imgur.com/a/NZV3e http://imgur.com/a/fhzSK

Comment: Dude, instead of serving from static files directly, consider using a lightweight static server like `http-server` (npm) or phyton's simpleHttpServer. I had similar issues as well when opening from static files on my browser. Both of the above program will run your project through a port (I think it's 8080). Check it out and lemme know if that changed anything.

Comment: OK, I did use a server (Apache to be exact), yet it still commits the same problematic act - It doesnt change the /contactus to /menu, but instead it adds an #menu to the already existing adress. I didn't say this, but what activates it is pressing the links in the navbar (menu or contactus or WE).

Answer (score 0):

Angular can not handle the  `/` in your link params (ie: `#/aboutus`).

Try to change your links from `href="#/pagename` to `href="#pagename`:

```
<a href="#aboutus">
<a href="#menu">
<a href="#contactus">
```

Comment: Hmmm, sadly i have tried any possible configuration of these likns.. both in the href's and even in the module itself (the part who takes the ngRoute).